# Design suggestion for RabbitmQ Producer & Consumer

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, design-patterns, rabbitmq

I have a RabbitMQ design question. Let say I have 6 exchanges and 10 queues and split up as below

- 5 exchange with type 'fanout' and has 5 queues bound to it
- 1 exchange with type 'topic' and it is routed to 5 different queues based on the routing key.

I have a microservice application which runs Kubernetes with the scale of 25 and all these applications acquire 1 rabbitmq connection per process. So 25 rabbitmq connections act as producer.

I have another application which also runs in Kubernetes with the scale of 1 and these applications acquire 1 rabbitmq connection. So 1 rabbitmq connection act as a consumer.

**Numbers:** Let say every exchange gets 100k messages per day.

**Tech stack**: Node.js + amqplib

**Questions:**

1. How many channels should producer needs to create for publishing the messages to exchanges?
2. How many channels should consumer needs to create for consuming the messages from the queues?
3. Is it a good approach to have one application act as a consumer which consumes the message from all the queues?
4. How can I scale the consumers automatically based on the queue size in Kubernetes?
5. Is it possible to build priority based on consumers? Let say due to heavy load conditions, I would like the consumers to stop consuming from a couple of queues and focus all the resources on the rest of the queues.
6. How many connections should producer & consumer create?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semantically, there will be publishing and consuming components in your system. Each should use a channel, primarily because [error reporting and handling is channel-scoped](https://www.rabbitmq.com/channels.html#error-handling).

Whether a single application should consume from "all" queues, entirely depends on how you structure your services.

Same for controlling what consumers consume from what queues. Usually queue and consumers have semantical "types" and serve certain purposes.

Simply adding more consumers and [increasing prefetch](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2014/04/14/finding-bottlenecks-with-rabbitmq-3-3/) will only work up to a point, a single queue has a [realistic throughput limit](https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html#runtime-characteristics).

Scaling application instances based on queue length (messages in Ready state specifically) involves monitoring individual queue metrics. That only [works with a small number of queues](https://www.rabbitmq.com/prometheus.html#metric-aggregation) (with e.g. 100K queues collecting all metrics from all them becomes really expensive).

A small application that monitors metrics of an individual queue or the totals, and updates the number of replicas of an app in a deployment using the Kubernetes API should do.